# do-while stopped working

Tags: c

Back again with another rookie question. While working on a function for my homework project I found that my menu wouldn't exit when I press X, it worked just an hour ago and I haven't changed anything in main(). I commented out all the code in my functions just to be sure that nothing in a function interfered. I just can't find any problem and would be grateful for any help.

```
int main()
{
    char val, enter;
    int c;
/* loopa med do-while */
do
{
printf("===============================\n");
printf("    Olja i Norge AB\n");
printf("===============================\n\n");
printf("  Artikelregister\n");
printf(" A. Lista artiklar\n");
printf(" B. L\x84gg till artikel\n");
printf(" C. Radera artikel\n");
printf(" D. \x8Endra artikel\n\n");
printf("  Kundregister\n");
printf(" E. Lista kunder\n");
printf(" F. L\x84gg till kund\n");
printf(" G. Radera kund\n");
printf(" H. \x8Endra kund\n\n");
printf("  Ordrar\n");
printf(" I. Best\x84ll\n");
printf(" J. Lista ordrar\n\n");
printf(" X. Avsluta\n");
printf("\n===============================");
printf("\n===============================\n");
printf("V\x84lj: ");
scanf("%c", &val);

    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != EOF && c != '\n');

    switch( val )
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
            printf("\n");
            artList();
            break;

        case 'B':
        case 'b':
            printf("\n");
            artAdd();
            break;

        case 'C':
        case 'c':
            artDel();
            break;

        case 'D':
        case 'd':
            artEdit();
            break;

        case 'E':
        case 'e':
            kundList();
            break;

        case 'F':
        case 'f':
            kundAdd();
            break;

        case 'G':
        case 'g':
            kundDel();
            break;

        case 'H':
        case 'h':
            kundEdit();
            break;

        case 'I':
        case 'i':
            order();
            break;

        case 'J':
        case 'j':
            orderList();
            break;

        case 'X':
        case 'x':
            break;
    }

    printf("\nTryck <ENTER> f\x94r att forts\x84tta.");
    scanf("%c", &enter);
    system("cls");

}while(val != 'X' || val != 'x');

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint:   instead of checking for 'X' and 'x', use the "tolower" or "toupper" functions and only compare once.  For example, after reading in your character, convert it to upper or lower case, then compare.  It will reduce frustration and size in your program. ;-)

Comment: @Thomas: are you sure that's a good rule of thumb? http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=415417

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
do { ... } while (val != 'X' || val != 'x');
```

if `val` is 'X' that while "converts" to

```
do { ... } while (0 || 1);
```

if `val` is 'x' that while "converts" to

```
do { ... } while (1 || 0);
```

if `val` is 'a' that while "converts" to

```
do { ... } while (1 || 1);
```

It never evaluates to false.

You need to rewrite the condition -- hint: use `&&` :)

---

*Edit*

Oh ... that's assuming the "`!=` has precedence over `||`". I never know what the precedence is, and I **always** use parenthesis in conditional expressions

```
do { ... } while ((val != 'X') || (val != 'x'));
```

Comment: Man, that's got to be one of the hardest things for new developers to learn, judging by all the and-or confusion I've seen.

Comment: +1 for explaining the answer not just giving a quick answer to gain rep.

Comment: Thanks, what confused me is that it worked great for a week, and now it just started working properly i guess

Comment: @Frederik: if it "does loop", then it must evaluate to `true`, not to `false` (as the loop keeps going _while_ the expression evaluates to true). And the answer explains why it always evaluates to `true`, including when you type `X` or `x`.

Comment: ... and, yes, `!=` has higher precedence than `||` (and `&&`).

Comment: Thanks Pavel, if you don't mind I'll continue to extra parenthesize my expressions with `||`, `&&`, `|`, `^`, and `&` :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't want to help you too much, but if you look at it carefully, this condition:

```
while(val != 'X' || val != 'x');
```

Will always evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
while(val != 'X' || val != 'x')
```

write

```
while(val != 'X' && val != 'x')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val != 'X' || val != 'x'
```

If `val == 'x'`, then `val != 'X'`, so the above is true. Similarly, the above is true when `val == 'X'`.